# Node.js Visual Studio 2013 - path too long error

Tags: node.js, path, visual-studio-2013

I am getting this error when trying to open my solution in VS with Node.js tools loaded:

> error  : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

My project path cannot be shorter, I am on the root of my drive.
I can open the solution if I move the "node_modules" folder out of the solution folder, so it seems to be something in there.

Comment: What is the error? What is the error preventing you from doing?

Comment: Now from node js 5, it is using a simplified folder structure for its packages and the dependencies are flattened and length of the folder path are shorter than previous ones. So it is wise to upgrade Node JS. FYI

Answer (score 2):

1. During release build, You can prevent Visual studio scanning
   these files / folder by setting the folder properties as a Hidden
   folder (JUST set it to node_modules). Reference:
   http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6219#comment=67-19103
2. You can exclude files or folder that are published during
   packaging by including following XML node in the CsProject file.

> <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' ==
>   'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
>   ...
>   <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
>        <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
>   <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>File1.aspx;File2.aspx</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
>   <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Folder1;Folder2
>   </PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an [Inline Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601) to the likes of [WebEssentials](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/master/EditorExtensions/PreBuildTask.cs) in your csproj file that will download the nodejs, it should be noted that in this process you will have to do a flatten your node modules and note that all the file path management should be done using Peter's [LongPath](https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath) library as it is especially made to handle the .NET problem of path length.

This is gonna be a pain in the ass, but this is worth a try.

Comment: The problem is there are several node_modules that have nested dependencies in them, at times these become duplicated as you might have it already in the upper level. It's just wise to flatten up all your NPMs and remove nested dependencies. This will work.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can't change the down vote unless the answer is edited though.

Comment: @iss42 I respect that, was trying to include all possibilities into a single answer

Answer (score 1):

This npm-package solved my issue :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatten-packages